# How do I copy specific cells from sheet 1 and paste into corresponding rows of sheet 2 , based on values of cells in sheet 2?

Tags: vba, excel

I have Sheet 1 with lots of columns, where column A is the list of all customer codes. In sheet 2 I have column A as some selected customer codes. Now based on the selected customer codes in sheet2 I need to extract few columns (H,I,J) from sheet1, paste it into sheet 2 and export the result to a new sheet.

Excel noob here. Hope you understood my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming customer codes are unique in column A (i.e., the same code does not appear multiple times) you can do all of this with `VLOOKUP` function.

No need for VBA.  In column B, Sheet 2: `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:J,8,False)` will return the value corresponding from column H (H being the *eighth* column of the range A:J).

Likewise do this for column I:

`=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:J,9,False)`

And if you guessed also do this for column J:

`=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:J,10,False)`